# How to choose the right inductor current limit for buck converter?

Tags: inductor, buck, surface-mount, inductance, maximum-ratings

While learning and trying to make my first two-phase buck converter to power some servos, I found 2 x 3.3 uH inductors are needed for an application that will draw 30A (15A each). The problem is that the switching buck converter IC [LM5143A-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva870a/snva870a.pdf?ts=1690099912547)(link to datasheet) has a max output current of 40A, so we're ***really*** close to its max specs. So, **what MAX current should I pick for the inductor's rating?** I found ones that [go as high as 30A](https://mouser.com/ProductDetail/Coilcraft/SER2915L-332KL?qs=zCSbvcPd3pawwAv2o3QV8w%3D%3D) MAX DC current. In theory, we only need 15A for each, but *isn't it **safe*** to go a bit higher? But then again, if we pick the 30A, then **won't that allow the inductors to draw 30A each** and literally burn the IC at 60A? If the application only draws 30A, it won't draw more than that, right? So it's safe to go with the higher rating ones?

I was also thinking going for a slightly higher current rating would lower the chances of heat going wild. **The operating frequency it'll use is 100kHz**

Comment: The 30-A limit you refer to is linked to the demo board, not the IC which drives two external MOSFETs. If you have 15 A dc in the inductor, the peak value will be half of the selected ripple above the dc. Also, something worth looking at is the inductance versus current curve for the type you've selected. Operating temperature also influences the inductor saturation limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current rating of the inductor won’t come into play until you hit the limit and the inductor saturates. Before that, the converter have no idea if you are using two 3.3 uH 30 A inductors or two 3.3 uH 60 A inductors.

Feel free to go higher in inductor current rating if you need lower DCR or optimal value isn’t available to you.